# UISegmentedControl segment order issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

i'm using the following code to set the color of each segment in UISegmentedControl.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.controlStatus numberOfSegments]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *ar=self.controlStatus.subviews;

        if ([[self.controlStatus titleForSegmentAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"ON"])
        {
            [[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        }
        else if ([[self.controlStatus titleForSegmentAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"OFF"])
        {
            [[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        }
        else if ([[self.controlStatus titleForSegmentAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"HIDE"])
        {
            [[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
        }
    }
```

But i'm not getting the color as i need in corresponding segment. Sometimes the colors are as follows: 
 
1st segment - GREEN 
 
2nd segment - ORANGE 
 
3rd segment - RED

But at some stage when i navigate to other pages and come back, the color changes: 
 
1st segment - RED 
 
2nd segment - ORANGE 
 
3rd segment - GREEN

Can anyone give me an idea about whats happening here.

Comment: Your are messing with the private subview structure of the segmented control. That's always a bad idea. Your code assumes the subviews are in the same order as the segments. Bad assumption.

Comment: Can u give me some suggestion on how to do this ?

Comment: Leaving a comment for anyone that might be looking for an answer in the future.
It is a really dirty way, but if you really have to do this:
What I did was, when first initialising the view controller, saving the subviews in my array in the correct order. Every time you select another segment the subviews of the segmented control shuffle, but in your array they are saved in the correct order. You can then manipulate the background colors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution. It'll meet my need..

```
    if(Status==0)
    {
        [self.controlStatus setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
        [self.controlStatus setEnabled:FALSE forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.controlStatus numberOfSegments]; i++)
        {
            if ([[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isSelected])
            {
                [[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            }
        }
    }
    else if(Status==1)
    {
        [self.controlStatus setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.controlStatus numberOfSegments]; i++)
        {
            if ([[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isSelected])
            {
                [[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            }
        }
    }
    else if(Status==2)
    {
        [self.controlStatus setSelectedSegmentIndex:2];
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.controlStatus numberOfSegments]; i++)
        {
            if ([[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isSelected])
            {
                [[self.controlStatus.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            }
        }

    }
```

I've written this code where i want to setSelectedSegmentIndex.

Comment: This code still digs around the private and undocumented subviews of the control. Code like this is fragile and can easily stop working or crash on the next iOS update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public method on UISegmentedControl to change the background color of each segment individually.

And you can't easily use image because a segment can have an image OR a title, but not both.

You can revert to make your own segmented control by using rect UIButtons in an UIView container with rounded corners and a border line:

```
- (void)setBorderWidth:(CGFloat)_borderWidth color:(UIColor *)_borderColor cornerRadius:(CGFloat)_cornerRadius
{
    CALayer *layer = self.layer;

    layer.borderWidth = _borderWidth;
    layer.borderColor = _borderColor.CGColor;
    layer.cornerRadius = _cornerRadius;
    layer.masksToBounds = (_cornerRadius > 0.0);
}
```